# Pandas - to_csv quoting list in cells

Tags: python, pandas

The original data contain Byte(list), Count(int)
The sample is like this

```
   Byte                 Count  Averager
0  [66, 66, 66]           3       66
1  [103, 103, 76]         3       94
```

After using to_csv(), the value of the Byte field has changed to string type

```
"[66, 66, 66]",3,66,"[103, 103, 76]",3,94
```

After I change the type of Byte by using `df.Byte = df.Byte.apply(ast.literal_eval)`
and `df.to_csv('Total.csv',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

However a Error raised:

```
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

After researching, I have add `df.to_csv('Total.csv',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escape='\\')`
and the output is like

```
[66\, 66\, 66\],3,66,[103\, 103\, 76\],3,94
```

How can I remove those quotes without adding other escape characters?
The expected result is:

```
[66, 66, 66],3,66,[103, 103, 76],3,94
```

Comment: Hi, df.to_csv('Total.csv',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ') add escape character[(' ') which is extra scape] and then try.

Comment: To us Nk03's way, `import csv` first.

Comment: Don't use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`... why are you passing that option?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve? pandas will never automatically parse some string representation of a list into a list when you load from csv.

Comment: @Nk03 I used  df.to_csv('Total.csv',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')  and the result become [66 , 66 , 66 ],3,66 [103 , 103 , 76 ],3,94  (space added in the list) But when I read('Total.csv'), another Error raise-: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 14932 fields in line 3, saw 69145

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just want to remove those quote in the lists

Comment: @KenChoi **of course**. You didn't set a escape character when you loaded your csv: `pd.read_csv('Total.csv', escapechar=' ')`

Comment: @KenChoi **why** to what end? Do you understand why those quotes are necessary?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're correct just add escapechar=' ' while reading ;)

Comment: Actually, The type of the "Byte" fields is string now. I have change it into lists with df.Byte = df.Byte.apply(ast.literal_eval). However, after I used to_csv and read it again, it become string again.

Comment: @KenChoi **it will always be a string when you read it from a csv**. This is what I've been trying to tell you and why I've been asking you what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I am trying to input this csv into a svm using svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train) . However ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[66, 66, 66] so i want to convert it back to list

Comment: juanpa is again right,  and @KenChoi if you wanna convert the string to the list. You might wanna use ast.literal_eval()

Comment: @Nk03. I have used ast.literal_eval() to change "Byte" back to list. But after to_csv and read it again, it become string again.

Comment: @KenChoi of course, why do you *ever expect it to work any other way*? I already explained to you, it will always treat it as a string

Comment: Whenever you're writing anything to a file it'll be written as a string. Whenever you're reading anything from a file it'll be treated as string. If you need to change the value before writing or after reading you need to do type casting. Use ast.literal_eval() to change it to list type before reading or after writing